# Python: nested dictionary is changing all values at once

Tags: python, dictionary

I need to generate nested dictionaries, so I wrote the function `create_nested`:

```
def create_nested():
    key_dict = {}
    for key in ['key1', 'key2']:
        key_dict[key] = 0

    nested_dict = {}
    for dictionary in ['dict1', 'dict2']:
        nested_dict[dictionary] = key_dict
    return nested_dict
```

Which will always return something like this:

```
{'dict1': {'key1': 0, 'key2': 0}, 'dict2': {'key1': 0, 'key2': 0}}
```

When a try to change one of the values this way:

```
x=create_nested()
x['dict1']['key2'] = 2
```

It gives me `{'dict1': {'key1': 0, 'key2': 2}, 'dict2': {'key1': 0, 'key2': 2}}`

Instead of `{'dict1': {'key1': 0, 'key2': 2}, 'dict2': {'key1': 0, 'key2': 0}}`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You created only 1 `key_dict` & made multiple keys in the other dict point to it. So obviously if you change that underlying object, that change is reflected everywhere.

Comment: In other words, `nested_dict[dictionary] = key_dict` does not make a copy of `key_dict`

Comment: You might take a look at https://docs.python.org/3/library/copy.html

Comment: Got it. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

Your `dict1` and `dict2` keys are referencing to the same `dict` object created before so any change performed on it will impact both key's values.

If you want to assign to your keys two different `dicts`, you should copy it:

```
import copy
def create_nested():
    key_dict = {}
    for key in ['key1', 'key2']:
        key_dict[key] = 0
        nested_dict = {}
    for dictionary in ['dict1', 'dict2']:
        nested_dict[dictionary] = copy.deepcopy(key_dict)
```

`deepcopy` will copy recursively all the elements inside your dict and will create an *independent* copy for you, so any change performed on it will impact only itself.

Answer (score 2):

When you assign the key_dict to multiple values in nested_dict, they will refer to the same object in memory (I hope my terminology is correct. Python is Pass-by-object-reference, full explaination here https://robertheaton.com/2014/02/09/pythons-pass-by-object-reference-as-explained-by-philip-k-dick/ )

```
for dictionary in ['dict1', 'dict2']:
        nested_dict[dictionary] = key_dict
    return nested_dict
```

now if I change nested_dict['dict1'] I'm changing the same memory that nested_dict['dict2'] knows about. In general, know which types are mutable, and expect them to change if another reference to it changes it.

A simple fix for dictionaries that only have immutable values is:

```
for dictionary_name in ['dict1', 'dict2']: # The variable name dictionary for a string is very confusing, so changing that.
        # create a new dictionary in memory
        nested_dict[dictionary_name] = {k: v for k, v in key_dict.items()}
    return nested_dict
```

If you have potentially values in key_dict that are mutable then you must make a deep copy. https://docs.python.org/3/library/copy.html